# An intuitive explanation of the primal-dual algorithm

Tags: optimization

I am a beginner to optimization, and I am trying to understand the primal-dual algorithm. However, all explanations I have seen so far are very maths-heavy. So it's very difficult to understand the details without having a broader appreciation of what is generally going on.

Can somebody give me an intuitive / wordy / analagous explanation of how the algorithm works, and what it is used for?

Thanks!

Comment: do you understand the concept of duality and duality gap? the primal-dual algorithm just tries to reduce the duality gap (in a controlled way)

Comment: No, I don't....I've tried looking into that, but again it is just full of complicated maths...!

Comment: It would be difficult to explain a month worth lecture in a SE post. It would be the best if you start with the duality theory and ask question about it in case you get stuck somewhere.